# I want to enable backup through adb

Tags: android, eclipse

I m new to the android. i want to do "enable backup with the following command from your SDK tools/ path: adb shell bmgr enable true"

plzz help me how to do this.

I have tried it in cmd bt it is giving me this error

C:\Program Files\Android\Android-sdk\tools>adb shell
'adb' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file

Answer (score 0):

//you can fine one adb_has_moved.txt in your tools folder

```
The adb tool has moved to platform-tools/

If you don't see this directory in your SDK,
launch the SDK and AVD Manager (execute the android tool)
and install "Android SDK Platform-tools"

Please also update your PATH environment variable to
include the platform-tools/ directory, so you can
execute adb from any location.
```

[how to set adb path in windows:](http://www.villainrom.co.uk/forum/threads/guide-setting-up-adb-and-how-to-use-it-windows.1655/)